# Atlassian Bamboo: Handling git-Flow hotfix-branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, bamboo

At our company we use Jira, Bitbucket and Bamboo. Our repository is organized in the git-flow schema:

- develop-branch = Application code for testing (aka Release Candidate)
- master-branch = Application code running live
- feature-branches = new components based on actual dev-branch merged via pull-request
- hotfix-branches = new hotfixes based on master-branch merged into develop and master via pull-request

Our versioning system works like the following:

[image]

Now I'm trying to integrate our structure into Bamboo. I created a plan triggered by changes into the dev-branch containing two stages:

- 1: Develop - Build develop -> deploy after finish
- 2: (manual) Production - Build master -> deploy after finish

That works fine with feature Branches. How do I handle hotfix branches? Do I need an additional plan or is it possible to create a single plan to cover the whole process?

Comment: how does that work now with feature branches? You first merge them to develop and then build is started?

Comment: Yeah, that's how it's working at the moment. First I let create bamboo a plan branch that runs tests and builds. Then the feature is merged into develop via bitbucket. That merge automatically triggers the develop build and pauses until production is being executed. 
Hotfix-Branches are kinda problematic, because the trigger is the master AND dev branch.