# Follow GitFlow Hotfix pattern with Bitbucket Pull Requests

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request, git-flow

I can't figure out how I can configure Bitbucket to handle Hotfixes the GitFlow way via one Pull Request (PR).

What I would like is:

- Submit a hotfix PR (to merge into master (production) branch).
- Once my PR approved, Bitbucket merge PR into master AND develop.

Actually, Bitbucket "automatic merging" merge PR into master then master into develop...

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35995408) seems to work the way I want. But I don't know if Crack_David use 2 PR (one for master and one for develop).

This is my actual Bitbucket config. For info.

[image]

Comment: I've searched quite a bit for an answer to this.  I couldn't find any solutions or issues on BitBucket's issue tracker. So I created one: [Request for hotfix to merge to develop and master](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/17710/gitflow-workflow-unable-to-merge-hotfix).  Hopefully, this feature is added.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic merges in bitbucket are a bit funky. From the graphic at the top of https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/automatic-branch-merging-776639993.html, automatic merging will merge A->B, then B->C, which is not what you want. You want A->B and A->C.

You'll need two separate pull requests I'm afraid.

Comment: Atlassian support answered this : "Referring to the screenshot page in the Branching Model, the Development branch should be your master branch whereas the Production branch should be you develop branch. This will allow hotfix/IC-1234 merge to master then hotfix/IC-1234 merge to develop.". It seems weird to me...

Comment: I think that's because of the way the ordering is supported in automatic merges. As I said, it's a bit funky. I've never liked it.